# Is there a way to see stdout from the Jenkins artifactory release plugin?

Tags: jenkins-plugins, artifactory

The Jenkins artifactory release plugin runs a bunch of git commands when releasing for example:

```
[RELEASE] Changing POMs to next development version
[RELEASE] Committing next development version on branch 'master'
[RELEASE] Pushing branch 'master' to ''
 > git --version # timeout=10
using GIT_SSH to set credentials jenkins-mod with full ssh keys
Finished: SUCCESS
```

The git output doesn't get printed to 'stdout' though. In the case above I would expect to see the git version to be printed out. Is there any way to get this output? It's hard to debug what is happening without the git stdout.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try starting Jenkins with the java option  `-Dhudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.verbose=true`.

The Artifactory plugin uses the git-client plugin. Options for enabling verbose output in the git client should apply. This option was added to the git-client plugin in this commit [2ca0d09e51810e83ab0d1893ecb87c64f0599210](https://github.com/dougm/jenkinsci-git-plugin/commit/2ca0d09e51810e83ab0d1893ecb87c64f0599210). I have git-client 2.6.0 installed and it works okay.

On my CentOS 7 system with Jenkins 1.651 I enabled the option by editing /etc/sysconfig/jenkins and adding it to the JENKINS_JAVA_OPTIONS variable. After that a restart with "systemctl restart jenkins" was used for it to take effect.

You can see it enabled by looking at the process list:

```
[root@jenkins]# ps aux | grep Git
build     3556  166  9.9 3576244 386416 ?      Ssl  15:10   0:18 /etc/alternatives/java -Dcom.sun.akuma.Daemon=daemonized -Djava.awt.headless=true -Dhudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.verbose=true -DJENKINS_HOME=/var/lib/jenkins -jar /usr/lib/jenkins/jenkins.war --logfile=/var/log/jenkins/jenkins.log --webroot=/var/cache/jenkins/war --daemon --httpPort=8080 --ajp13Port=8009 --debug=5 --handlerCountMax=100 --handlerCountMaxIdle=20
```

Comment: I edited the jenkins init script to add the parameter, but jenkins wouldn't start after doing that.

Comment: Updated with more detail to help out.